# Detail on a theorem of continuity and compactness

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I have come across a proof in a book. I have trouble convincing myself on a statement on said proof.
The theorem is a well-known one. I am stating the version I found on Ross's "Elementary Analysis." I will first state the theorem, then the proof, and then the questions.

$\underline{21.4\;\;Theorem}$

Consider metric spaces $(S,d)$, $(S^{*},d^{*})$ and a continuous function $f:S\rightarrow S^*$. Let $E$ be a compact subset of $S$. Then

(i) $f(E)$ is a compact subset of $S^*$, and

$Proof$

To prove (i), let $\;\mathcal{U}\;$ be an open over of $f(E)$. For each $U
\in\mathcal{U}$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in S. Moreover, $\{f^{-1}(U):U\in\mathcal{U}\}\;$ is a cover of $E$.

I am having trouble convincing myself that the last sentence in the proof above is true. I know that  $f^{-1}(U)$ is open by a theorem. However, I do not know how to go from there to the conclusion that  $\{f^{-1}(U):U\in\mathcal{U}\}\;$ is a cover of $E$. What theorems are relevant and what are the references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in E$. Then as $\mathscr U$ is a cover of $f(E)$, $f(x)\in U$ for some $U$. Thus $x\in f^{-1}(U)$.